# Fail2ban on Debian Buster - the right way to configure?

Tags: fail2ban, debian-buster

Fail2ban can be configured in so many places.

```
$ fail2ban-client -i 
Fail2Ban v0.10.2 reads log file that contains password failure report
and bans the corresponding IP addresses using firewall rules.
```

On Debian Buster I can edit my settings in several config files:

```
/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/defaults-debian.conf
/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf
/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
/etc/fail2ban/action.d/
```

And - last but not least - some tutorials recommend:

```
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

The [Documentation](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) of fail2ban says:

*Modifications should take place in the .local and not in the .conf. This avoids merging problem when upgrading. These files are well documented and detailed information should be available there.*

Does that mean, that every .conf File I want to edit should exist as a .local file?

I am confused! Can someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Adding to your line from the docs: _Every .conf file can be overridden with a file named .local. The .conf file is read first, then .local, with later settings overriding earlier ones. Thus, a .local file doesn't have to include everything in the corresponding .conf file, only those settings that you wish to override._. So yes, your assumption is correct. Nothing stops you from altering the `.conf` files, if you want to, though.

Comment: If you accepted the answer from @corni, it seems his answer is also worth an upvoat?  Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to edit one file.

To avoid problems during system upgrades, you should always copy `jail.conf` to `jail.local` and modify the latter only. The same for all other fail2ban config files.

```
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Then edit this file and scroll down to the filters you want to use.

In those filters, add `enabled = true`. I recommend not to enable too many filters at the beginning. One or two is enough. Be carefull with the SSH filter if you're are connected via SSH. You might lock yourself out.

**Filters**

Look in the `filter.d` directory to see all available filters. Choose one or two suitable ones. Be sure to understand what their regexes match and what log files you need.

Fail2ban works with log files. So the filters must match the appropriate log files. You can test this with

`fail2ban-regex <logfile> <filter>`

For example

`fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/default_access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-botsearch.conf`

This filter - for example - looks for `404` errors in your NGINX `access.log` and blocks them, if the conditions match. For the conditions, see below.

Restart fail2ban after you finished editing:

```
systemctl restart fail2ban
```

**Other settings in your `jail.local` file:**

All settings can be made global as well as filter specific.

```
bantime  = 7200
findtime  = 10m
maxretry = 10
```

means 10 errors in 10 minutes will result in a 2 hour ban.

If you don't want to use iptables for the banning, you can change your `banaction`. The default banaction uses iptables, which should work on all systems I know but you might not see the bans in your familiar firewall interface.

```
banaction = ufw
```

See the actions in `action.d`. With this setting, fail2ban will use ufw to block IPs. Then you can see the ban via `ufw status`.

Especially for SSH, be sure to exclude your local IP range from banning, so you can't ban yourself :

```
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 ::1 192.168.178.0/24
```

I would suggest you **not** to create or modify new filters or actions. Use the included ones and be happy. It's not easy to buiild your own regex patterns and the log file format changes from time to time - which will break your filters. Your system won't be secured then. You should not edit `Apaches` default log format, too.